# Evaluating functions at matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

### Try:

So far, I know that if $f(x) = \sum a_i x^i$ is a polynomial, then for square matrix $A$ one has $f(A) = \sum a_i A^i $ where $A^0 = I$. However, here we have non-polynomials functions that can be approximated by polynomials via taylors trick. However, do we get the result if we apply directly A into f? that is

$$ f(A) = \begin{bmatrix}  e^{-3 \pi /8} & 1 & e^{-\pi/8} \\
                          1 & e^{4 \pi /8} & 1 \\
                         e^{- \pi /8} & 1 & e^{3\pi/8} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

And similarly, for $g$ and $h$. Can we do this? Or do we need to expand each in taylor's series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply $f$ to each element of the matrix. For a simple counterexample consider $A=\begin {bmatrix} 0 &1 \\0 & 0 \end {bmatrix}$. Let $f(x)=x^{2}$. Then $f(A)=A^{2}$ is the zero matrix but if you apply $f$ to each element you get $A$. One way of finding functions of the matrix is to diagonalize. The given matrix is p0sitive definite so it can be written as $S^{-1}DS$ where $D$ is diagonal. We have $f(A)=S^{-1}f(D)S$ and $f(D)$ can be calculated by applying $f$ to the diagonal elements. This works each of the three functions under consideration.

Comment: How then do you evaluate such expressions?

Comment: @JimmySabater I have given a suggestion for finding functions of the given matrix.